# Python Setting Values Without Loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series dataframe where there is 1 or 0 in it (true/false). I wrote a function that loops through all rows with values 1 in them. Given user defined integer parameter called `n_hold`, I will set values 1 to n rows forward from the initial row.

For example, in the dataframe below I will be loop to row `2016-08-05`. If `n_hold = 2`, then I will set both `2016-08-08` and `2016-08-09` to 1 too.:

```
2016-08-03    0
2016-08-04    0
2016-08-05    1
2016-08-08    0
2016-08-09    0
2016-08-10    0
```

The resulting `df` will then is

```
2016-08-03    0
2016-08-04    0
2016-08-05    1
2016-08-08    1
2016-08-09    1
2016-08-10    0
```

The problem I have is this is being run 10s of thousands of times and my current solution where I am looping over rows where there are ones and subsetting is way too slow. I was wondering if there are any solutions to the above problem that is really fast.

Here is my (slow) solution, `x` is the initial signal dataframe:

```
n_hold = 2
entry_sig_diff = x.diff()
entry_sig_dt = entry_sig_diff[entry_sig_diff == 1].index
final_signal = x * 0
for i in range(0, len(entry_sig_dt)):
    row_idx = entry_sig_diff.index.get_loc(entry_sig_dt[i])

    if (row_idx + n_hold) >= len(x):
        break

    final_signal[row_idx:(row_idx + n_hold + 1)] = 1
```

Comment: Can you show your allow approach for completeness?

Comment: is there a function in pandas that spit out the dataframe that I use so I can post it here so you guys can use it? I remember I did it once but forgot if its in R or python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely changed answer, because working differently with consecutive `1` values:

**Explanation**:

Solution remove each consecutive `1` first by [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with chained boolean mask by comparing with [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (not equal `!=`) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) to `NaN`s, forward filling them by `ffill` with `limit` parameter and last replace `0` back:

```
n_hold = 2
s = x.where(x.ne(x.shift()) & (x == 1)).ffill(limit=n_hold).fillna(0, downcast='int')
```

Timings and comparing outputs:

```
np.random.seed(123)
x = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0,1], p=(.8,.2), size=1000))
x1 = x.copy()
#print (x)


def orig(x):
    n_hold = 2
    entry_sig_diff = x.diff()
    entry_sig_dt = entry_sig_diff[entry_sig_diff == 1].index
    final_signal = x * 0
    for i in range(0, len(entry_sig_dt)):
        row_idx = entry_sig_diff.index.get_loc(entry_sig_dt[i])

        if (row_idx + n_hold) >= len(x):
            break

        final_signal[row_idx:(row_idx + n_hold + 1)] = 1
    return final_signal

#print (orig(x))
```

---

```
n_hold = 2
s = x.where(x.ne(x.shift()) & (x == 1)).ffill(limit=n_hold).fillna(0, downcast='int')
#print (s)

df = pd.concat([x,orig(x1), s], axis=1, keys=('input', 'orig', 'new'))
print (df.head(20))
    input  orig  new
0       0     0    0
1       0     0    0
2       0     0    0
3       0     0    0
4       0     0    0
5       0     0    0
6       1     1    1
7       0     1    1
8       0     1    1
9       0     0    0
10      0     0    0
11      0     0    0
12      0     0    0
13      0     0    0
14      0     0    0
15      0     0    0
16      0     0    0
17      0     0    0
18      0     0    0
19      0     0    0

#check outputs
#print (s.values == orig(x).values)
```

**Timings**:

```
%timeit (orig(x))
24.8 ms ± 653 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit x.where(x.ne(x.shift()) & (x == 1)).ffill(limit=n_hold).fillna(0, downcast='int')
1.36 ms ± 12.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: is this faster then a simple loop?

Comment: @user1234440 - I hope so, best test it. Or if add your solution I can add timings.

Comment: @user1234440 - Unfortunately solution is a bit complicated, added new one, explanation and also timings.